# Do ISO files store their creation date within the ISO data itself?

Tags: iso-image

I know the files and folders stored inside the ISO have date/time information, but I want to know if the header info has the date the ISO file was created, please?

Comment: Open the iso with 7zip. You can see all the date of every files and folders.

Comment: I said that above already. What I mean is, does the ISO file generated have a date of the creation of the ISO file itself?

Comment: [Software to view metadata of an ISO file?](//superuser.com/q/246325)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes.  If you open the ISO image in a text editor such as Notepad, you can see the metadata, which includes the creation date as well as other information.